# SVN Authorization error when accessing repository

Tags: svn, windows-7, configuration

This is more a configuration question than a programming question.  If there is a better place to post this, please redirect me.

I am getting an authorization error when I try to import a project with TortoiseSVN.  I am in control of the client (my PC) and the SVN repository (another PC on a non-routing network).  The client and server are on Windows 7.  There is an Active Directory (that I'm not in control of) to validate user names and passwords.  I can login to both client and server.

The server is running svnserve as a Windows service.  I have two repositories on the server, one in `c:\repositories\repo1` that is a mirror of another repository.  It updates and svnsync and works just fine.  The second is `c:\repositories\repo2` and is supposed to be a test repository for integration testing.  I have not successfully written to this second repository.

I use the URL `svn://<pc_name>/repo2/` as the root for the import.  When I right-click on the project folder on my client and go into Tortoise Import, I put in `svn://<pc_name>/repo2/project1` as the URL.

On the server, I have in `<repo2_folder>conf/svnserve.conf`:

```
anon-access = write
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
```

(I have tried `anon-access = read` too.)  In passwd I have the user name and password.  In authz I have:

```
[repository:/repo1]
* = r

[repository:/repo2]
<username>= rw
```

I have tried every combination that I can think of and I still get an authorization error.  Any ideas?

EDIT:

This has nothing to do with TortoiseSVN.  I can get the same problem without it:

```
C:\>svn list svn://pc0000/repo2 --username ksnortum --password xxxxxxxxx
svn: Authorization failed
```

Comment: can you **see** empty repo2 with TSVN? I'm afraid, for 2 repos on 1 daemon your path may be bad

Comment: With anon-access = write none authentication is performed

Comment: @Lazy Badger: yes, I can see repo2 and it's empty.  I found an article about two repos and one daemon (service in this case) so it must have worked at least once!  ;-)

Comment: I've tried `anon-access = write` but I still get authorization failures.  Should I comment out `auth-access`?  I'm in a small network behind a firewall so I could live with no authorization.

Comment: I commented out `auth-access`.  TSVN doesn't ask for a user name and password, but I still get an authorization error.

Comment: anon-access = **none** and try to import from CLI

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8553/discussion-between-ksnortum-and-lazy-badger)

Comment: @ksnortum - Have you ever managed to resolve this using svnserve?

Answer (score 0):

You must set anon-access = none.  You do NOT want to allow anonymous access.  With the settings you have in place your server will never challenge you for credentials and therefore your access rules will never be met.

While you can supply credentials on the command line, it is not possible for the client to "push" credentials to the server.  It will only use those credentials if the server challenges it.

Comment: I changed `anon-access = none` in `repo2/conf/svnserve.conf`.  I restarted the svnserve Windows service.  On the client PC I typed `svn list svn://<pc_name>/repo2`.  I did not get an authorization challenge.  I did get an authorization failed error.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using svnserve?  Apache is easier, IMO.  You can install CollabNet Subversion Edge which is free and it handles all these details for you.  I do note that the syntax of your authz file is wrong.  The entries should look like [repos1:/]

Comment: I used svnserve because it was presented as a better, simple server.  I do have Apache on the server and I may try it since this isn't working.  I noticed the repo section problem too.  What is a "repository name"?  Something I make up?  I have two repositories so I would need `[foo:/repo1/]` and `[bar:/repo2/]`.